# EventHistoryCollector - increase page size

Tags: java, vmware, page-size, vmware-sdk

I need to collect the 20 latest events from EventHistoryCollector. `GetLatestEvents()` gets me the 10 latest events and `readNextEvents()` gets me how many ever events I want in some haphazard order that I can't use. Is there a way of setting page size for the EventHistoryCollector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/vi-sdk/visdk250/ReferenceGuide/vim.HistoryCollector.html#setLatestPageSize). Should have googled first :|